# Accessing original files on a domain which has A-Record redirect to tumblr

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

Hosting a tumblr on a custom domain, but allowing access to files that are at that domain, that are outside of the tumblr CMS.

The custom domain I've got two A-Record DNS entries that point over to tumblr. One for the two-level domain (example.com), and one for three-level domains (www.example.com). All well and good. This works.

However, I host other pages on the domain, and following the A-Record redirects I can no longer access them. I would like all traffic going to the root domain to be served the tumblr page, but I would still like to be able to serve further pages on that domain that are independent of tumblr. For example:

```
http://example.com/anythinghere/file
```

The only solution I have been able to think of is to associate tumblr only with the three level domain, and put a redirect file at the root of the two level domain that redirects people hitting the two level root over to the three level domain

i.e. `http://example.com` redirects to `http://www.example.com`, which then serves tumblr.

This allows that I can still access the files  on the server by addressing them only at two levels. I.e:

`http://example.com/stillaccessible` vs. `http://www.example.com/notacessible`

but this seems clumsy, the URLs are inelegant. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question.

You can only point an A record to one place[1]. If you can't have Tumblr point requests for `/anythinghere/file` back to your server (either by IP Address or another A record such as `server.example.com`), then you have you point the A record to your server, and have your server handle redirecting traffic for anything that isn't a file on your server to Tumblr.

*[1] You can have multiple A records the same pointing to different addresses, but each request from a client will only go to one of those addresses.*

Comment: yohkay, going to keep it clean by setting up a subdomain for all non-tumblr things. thanks